# Most concise way to combine sequence elements

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Say we have two sequences and we and we want to combine them using some method

```
val a = Vector(1,2,3)
val b = Vector(4,5,6)
```

for example addition could be

```
val c = a zip b map { i => i._1 + i._2 }
```

or

```
val c = a zip b map { case (i, j) => i + j }
```

The repetition in the second part makes me think this should be possible in a single operation. I can't see any built-in method for this. I suppose what I really want is a zip method that skips the creation and extraction of tuples.

Is there a prettier / more concise way in plain Scala, or maybe with Scalaz? If not, how would you write such a method and pimp it onto sequences so I could write something like

```
val c = a zipmap b (_+_)
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Scala, but if I'm understanding the question I think you want an equivalent of the Haskell function `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`. I get some google hits for "scala zipwith" so that might be a place to look, as well.

Comment: @C. Thanks - this led me to this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157564/mapping-over-multiple-seq-in-scala and this ticket: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1512, which confirm that the Scala equivalent ot `zipWith` is `zipped` as per Rex's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is

```
(a,b).zipped.map(_ + _)
```

which is probably close enough to what you want to not bother with an extension.  (You can't use it point-free, unfortunately, since the implicits on `zipped` don't like that.)

Answer (score 2):

[Rex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068031/most-concise-way-to-combine-sequence-elements/7068101#7068101) is certainly the easier way out for *most* cases. However, `zipped` is more limited than `zip`, so you might stumble upon cases where it won't work.

For those cases, you might try this:

```
val c = a zip b map (Function tupled (_+_))
```

Or, alternatively, if you do have a function or method that does what you want, you have this option as well:

```
def sumFunction = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
def sumMethod(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b

val c1 = a zip b map sumFunction.tupled
val c2 = a zip b map (sumMethod _).tupled
```

Using `.tupled` won't work in the first case because Scala won't be able to infer the type of the function.