# Apply function on each elements in one list using element from others list as argument?

Tags: scala

I am not sure how to call this but I want something like this.

```
val x = List(1,2,3,...)
val y = List(4,5,6,...)
//want a result of List(1+4, 5+6, 7+8,...)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in scala ? My current implementation involving using looping from 0 to x.lenght which is pretty ugly. And if it is possible, I would like the solution that could use over nth number of list and maybe with other type of operator beside +.

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157564/mapping-over-multiple-seq-in-scala, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068031/most-concise-way-to-combine-sequence-elements

Comment: Yeah, it's a duplicate.  zipWith is still not in Scala, and Martin's answer still works - and is easy.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have more than 3 list ? It seems those solution limit itself to tuple, which pretty much could do only over three list.

Comment: (List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9)).zipped map (_ + _ + _) // yields List(12, 15, 18) (EDIT: oops, I read '2 lists' there somehow.  You're right, this doesn't extend to a fourth list.)

Comment: 5+6, 7+8 or 2+5, 3+6...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In response to "what if I have more than 3 list?":

```
def combineAll[T](xss: Seq[T]*)(f: (T, T) => T) = 
  xss reduceLeft ((_,_).zipped map f)
```

Use like this:

```
scala> combineAll(List(1,2,3), List(2,2,2), List(4,5,6), List(10,10,10))(_+_)
res5: Seq[Int] = List(17, 19, 21)
```

edit: alternatively

```
def combineAll[T](xss: Seq[T]*)(f: (T, T) => T) = 
  xss.transpose map (_ reduceLeft f)
```

does the same and is probably more efficient.