# Scala equivalent of R's Mapply?

Tags: r, scala, foreach, mapply

I come from a R background, so I'm accustomed to using R's *apply family of functions.

Scala's `list.foreach(_.fun)` and `list.map(_.fun)` functions are very similar to R's `lapply(list, fun)` function, in that they both iteratively perform a function over each element of a list.

However, R also has a function `mapply(fun, list1, list2, ...)`, which is useful when one has several lists and wants to apply a function over the first element of each, the second element of each, and so on. For example, if I had a function `add(x, y, z)`, and two lists `x=(1, 2, 3)`, `y=(2, 3, 4)`, and `z=(3, 4, 5)`, `mapply(add, x, y, z)` would return `(6, 9, 12)`.

Does Scala have any equivalent to R's `mapply`, without using a for-loop?

Comment: Can someone explain why this question was downvoted? I'm asking a programming question which was not easily Google-able and did not seem to have a duplicate on Stack Overflow. Downvoting without commenting does not contribute to the community.

Comment: I did not downvote you, however since I also dislike downvotes without comments and I have enough rep to see why people are voting to close your post I can tell you. They are pointing to the rule that says "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it"

Comment: How about this: https://dahl.byu.edu/software/rscala/rscala-jss.pdf . You can just use `mapply` in Scala!

Comment: I don't know Scala, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322191/apply-function-on-each-elements-in-one-list-using-element-from-others-list-as-ar) seems like the same general question.

Comment: @Hack-R: That's a really interesting package! I think it's overkill to actually switch to R programming for an issue like this, but it's cool that option exists.

Comment: @RichardScriven: After reading your link, it seems like `zipped` is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no analogous routine in the Standard Library, but you can get close:

```
scala> List(List(1,2,3),List(5,6,7),List(14,13,12)).transpose
res3: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 5, 14), List(2, 6, 13), List(3, 7, 12))

scala> List(List(1,2,3),List(5,6,7),List(14,13,12)).transpose.map(_.sum)
res4: List[Int] = List(20, 21, 22)
```

Note: `transpose` requires all sub-collections have the same size.

---

**Followup** to your comment.

I'm not sure you understand what `zipped` is. It transforms 2 sub-collections, inside a tuple (`Tuple2`), into a single collection of tuples, each of which can then be given to a function that takes 2 parameters of the given types.  This is also available for 3 sub-collections, inside a `Tuple3`, becoming a collection of triples, but that's the limit.

Also, I don't know why you think "`zipped` is one function call as opposed to two".  If you follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322191/apply-function-on-each-elements-in-one-list-using-element-from-others-list-as-ar) Richard Scriven suggested in his comment, and compare the two solutions offered, you'll see that they have the same number of steps/statements.

As I see it, the advantages/disadvantages breakdown as follows:

- If you're dealing with collections of different types, say `Seq[Int]` and `Seq[Char]`, then you'll want to get them `zipped` before applying the "combiner" function to them: `f(i1,c1)` then `f(i2,c2)` then `f(i3,c3)` etc.
- Neither approach handles sub-collections of different sizes well.  `transpose` will throw an exception while `zipped` simply ignores all elements beyond the max-index of the smallest sub-collection.
- If your "combiner" function takes more than three arguments then you can't use `zipped`.
- If your "combiner" takes a collection as input, then `transpose` is probably the better/easier option.

Comment: Clever solution! Do you know if this solution is any better than using `zipped`? The end result seems the same, except that `zipped` is one function call as opposed to two.

Comment: My assessment of `zipped` has been added to offered answer.