# Using foldleft or some other operator to calculate point distances?

Tags: scala, collections

Ok so I thought this would be a snap, trying to practice Scala's collection operators and my example is a list of points.

The class can calculate and return the distance to another point (as double).

However, fold left doesn't seem to be the right solution - considering elements e1, e2, e3.. I need a moving window to calculate, I need the last element looked at to carry forward in the function - not just the sum

```
Sum {
  e1.dist(e2)
  e2.dist(e3)
  etc
}
```

Reading the API I noticed a function called "sliding", perhaps that's the correct solution in conjunction with another operator. I know how to do this with loops of course, but trying to learn the scala way.

Thanks

```
import scala.math._

case class Point(x:Int, y:Int) {
  def dist(p:Point) = sqrt( (p.x-x)^2+(p.y-y)^2 )

}

object Point {

  //Unsure how to define this?
  def dist(l:Seq[Point]) =l.foldLeft(0.0)((sum:Double,p:Point)=>)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it as a fold, you can, but you need the accumulator to keep both the total and the previous element:

```
l.foldLeft(l.head, 0.0){ 
  case ((prev, sum), p) => (p, sum + p.dist(prev)) 
}._2
```

You finish with a tuple consiting of the last element and sum, so use `._2` to get the sum part.

btw, `^` on Int is bitwise logical XOR, not power. Use `math.pow`.

The smartest way is probably using `zipped`, which is a kind of iterator so you don't traverse the list more than once as you would using `zip`:

```
(l, l.tail).zipped.map( _ dist _ ).sum
```

Comment: Thanks for catching my ^ error, I had thought perhaps this was to match the concept of functions. Can you please explain further what "zipped" is - it seems "zip" also works, I can't find much detail on it in the Seq API or how it differs from zip.

Comment: It's a method on Tuple2. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7068031/770361 and linked answers or post another question!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but assuming you want the sum of the distances:

```
l.zip(l.tail).map { case (x,y) => x.dist(y) }.sum
```

Or with sliding:

```
l.sliding(2).map { 
  case List(fst,snd) => fst.dist(snd)
  case _ => 0
}.sum
```