# Scala: What does zipped produce and why can it be mapped as a pair?

Tags: scala

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157564/zipwith-mapping-over-multiple-seq-in-scala) about `zipWith`, @Martin Odersky suggested that instead of something like

```
 foo zipWith(_ + _) bar
```

(where `foo` and `bar` are `Seq`'s) that the following is better (and actually works in Scala).

```
(foo, bar).zipped map (_ + _)
```

My question is how does `map` know that its argument (which superficially would seem to be a pair) should be split into its two elements?

The following actually runs in a worksheet.

```
val list1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4)                    //> list1  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val list2 = List(5, 6, 7, 8)                    //> list2  : List[Int] = List(5, 6, 7, 8)
val zippedResult = (list1, list2).zipped        //> list3  : scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped[Int,List[Int],Int,List[Int]] = scala.run
                                              //| time.Tuple2Zipped@f4bf78da
zippedResult.mkString(", ")                     //> res4: String = (1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)
zippedResult map (_ + _)                        //> res5: List[Int] = List(6, 8, 10, 12)
```

I see that `zippedResult` in fact has 4 type parameters and is not just a list of pairs.

```
val list3 = List((1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8))
                                              //> list3a  : List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8))
list3 == zippedResult                           //> res6: Boolean = false
```

And I can't write

```
list3 map(_ +_ )
```

So what is the `Tuple2Zipped` type that it can supply two parameters to the `map` function? And is `zipped` the only way to create instances of it?

Comment: While you can't write `map(_ + _)` for a `.zipped` sequence, you can still use case matching to get at the individual elements: `list3 map { case (a,b) => a+b }`. Not as short, but it's something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [`runtime.Tuple2Zipped`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped). You can create an instance manually like this:

```
val zipped = new Tuple2Zipped(Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4))
```

Here is the [source of `map` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/runtime/Tuple2Zipped.scala#L33).

Method `map` is declared like this (simplified):

```
def map[B](f: (El1, El2) => B): Seq[B]
```

`Tuple2Zipped` is not an descendant of any scala collection type, so its `map` method has nothing with `map` method of regular scala collections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense that it would be a special case and that its `map` would be different from all the other `map`'s. I'm surprised that this hasn't received more publicity.

Comment: That's quite a discovery, never thought there's something collection-like but standing apart. Also there's `Tuple3Zipped`, which allows more funny constructs `(a, b, c).zipped map (_ * _ + _)`. That's a pity there is no continuation after 3.