# Zip two lists of different lengths with default element to fill

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Assume we have the following lists of different size:

```
val list1 = ("a", "b", "c")
val list2 = ("x", "y")
```

Now I want to merge these 2 lists and create a new list with the string elements being concatenated:

```
val desiredResult = ("ax", "by", "c")
```

I tried

```
val wrongResult = (list1, list2).zipped map (_ + _)
```

as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157564/zipwith-mapping-over-multiple-seq-in-scala), but this doesn't work as intended, because zip discards those elements of the longer list that can't be matched.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to zip the lists and give a "default element" (like the empty string in this case) if one list is longer?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`.zipAll`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#zipAll%5BA1%3E:A,B%5D(that:Iterable%5BB%5D,thisElem:A1,thatElem:B):CC%5B(A1,B)%5D):

```
scala> val list1 = List("a", "b", "c")
list1: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val list2 = List("x", "y")
list2: List[String] = List(x, y)

scala> list1.zipAll(list2, "", "")
res0: List[(String, String)] = List((a,x), (b,y), (c,""))
```

---

`.zipAll` takes 3 arguments:

- the iterable to zip with
- the default value if `this` (the collection `.zipAll` is called on) is shorter
- the default value if the other collection is shorter

Comment: Thanks! Now it works with this solution: `list1.zipAll(list2, "", "") map ({ case (y, x) => y + x })` but not like before with `list1.zipAll(list2, "", "") map (_ + _)`. Why can't I use the short syntax with the zipAll like the zipped function?

Comment: @ForceOfWill: `(list1, list2).zipped` returns a `Tuple2Zipped`, where [`.map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped@map[B,To](f:(El1,El2)=>B)(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr1,B,To]):To) takes a `f:(El1,El2)=>B` (ie a function that takes 2 arguments). `List[A]`'s `.map` takes a `f: A => B`, ie only 1 argument (which in this case is a `Tuple2`). Unfortunately this means that `_ + _` (which is a function that takes 2 arguments) can't be applied here.

Comment: The explaination for the three arguments was the best part. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The API-based `zipAll` is the way to go, yet you can implement it (as an exercise) for instance as follows,

```
implicit class OpsSeq[A,B](val xs: Seq[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def zipAll2(ys: Seq[B], xDefault: A, yDefault: B) = {
    val xs2 = xs ++ Seq.fill(ys.size-xs.size)(xDefault)
    val ys2 = ys ++ Seq.fill(xs.size-ys.size)(yDefault)
    xs2.zip(ys2) 
  }
}
```

Hence for instance

```
Seq(1,2).zipAll2(Seq(3,4,5),10,20)
List((1,3), (2,4), (10,5))
```

and

```
list1.zipAll2(list2, "", "")
List((a,x), (b,y), (c,""))
```

A recursive version,

```
def zipAll3[A,B](xs: Seq[A], ys: Seq[B], xd: A, yd: B): Seq[(A,B)] = {
  (xs,ys) match {
    case (Seq(),    Seq())    => Seq()
    case (x +: xss, Seq())    => (x,yd) +: zipAll3(xss, Seq(), xd, yd)
    case (Seq(),    y +: yss) => (xd,y) +: zipAll3(Seq(), yss, xd, yd)
    case (x +: xss, y +: yss) => (x,y) +: zipAll3(xss, yss, xd, yd) 
  }
}
```

with default `xd` and default `yd` values.